# On windows 7, thread appears to be hung at _endthreadex and Waitforsingleobject with a timeout doesn't signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-7

I need your help with a random hang issue we are facing with our desktop application.

We have a thread implemented in a singleton class to call Beep and Sleep APIs in a loop. So we start the thread to call these and then after some time, we break the loop, waitforsingleobject with a timeout in the main thread and come out of the thread. Just before returning from the thread function, we call _endthreadex. There is a hang here. Now I dont know whether the _endthreadex is failing and how it is stopping the waitforsingleobject from signalling after the timeout. The code is implemented pretty much similar to what is documented as an example for _beginthreadex. As I said, it occurs very randomly and on few machines.

```
unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )

{

printf( "In second thread...\n" );

while( m_iBeepMode == iBEEPON )

{

Beep(600, 100);

Sleep(100);

}

//I added a logging here, which gets logged in hang case.

_endthreadex( 0 );

return 0;

}

int main()

{

HANDLE hThread;

unsigned threadID;

printf( "Creating second thread...\n" );

// Create the second thread.

hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 16384, &SecondThreadFunc, this, 0, &threadID );

// the below code is not exactly in the same method. We call it at a later time to stop the beep.

m_iBeepMode = BEEPOFF;

WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 10000 );

// Added a logging here, which doesn't get logged.

// Destroy the thread object.

CloseHandle( hThread );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your  m_iBeepMode atomic so that it will be checked on each iteration. As it stands, since the compiler can see that nothing in that function changes  m_iBeepMode the condition may well be removed entirely.

Note this used to be the realm of volatile but atomic is the much more idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That would mean that it is stuck in the while loop? I had added logging within the while loop also and just after loop. I could see that iterations are happening and we are correctly coming out of the while loop.